# Coveralls not sending Pull Request status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-coverage, circleci, coveralls

I develop in Rails, keep my code in Github, use CircleCI for testing, and now I've been trying to introduce Coveralls in the picture.

I've set these settings in Coveralls:
[image]

I added the coveralls gem:
[image]

And I set up spec_helper.rb as instructed in Coveralls' documentation:
[image]

What is working:
CircleCi sends coverage information to Coveralls, and I can see the coverage reports.

What is not working: Coveralls doesn't send the pull request status so I can't see in Github whether a PR meets the coverage expectations as shown here in one of their ads: [image]

If anyone went through the Coveralls-CircleCI setup, I would really appreciate some pointers on this.

Comment: I've got the same problem even with Travis-CI. Those comments used to work but then stopped and nobody knows why. See e.g. https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/724

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and in my case the problem was that I invoked `coveralls` from a place where the `git` command did not work.

So I simply moved the `.coverage` file to the top of the repo prior to invoking `coveralls` and it fixed the problem.